# ALBD service is getting stopped

Tags: clearcase

I have installed the Rational ClearCase Server v7.1.2 but during the installation i have given  wrong group name for the Clearcase Adminstrator Group and so my Atria location broker service is getting stopped immeidately after starting.

How do i change the group name now without reinstalling the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the albd service's user account.

Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services > Atria Location Broker > Properties > Log On.

The group itself is in the Windows registry:

Set the following Windows registry key to a valid ClearCase group name:

- 32-bit Windows: 
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Atria\ClearCase\CurrentVersion\ClearCaseGroupName`
- 64-bit Windows: 
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Atria\ClearCase\CurrentVersion\ClearCaseGroupName`

See:

- "[Atria Location Broker service will not start following a new ClearCase server installation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21298188)"
- "[Troubleshooting ALBD startup failures on Windows](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21177467)"